React editable table resets to first page after search
I am trying to implement a React Editable table where each cell is an input where the user can modify it. I also added a global search and pagination to this table. The problem arises when i try to search in the global search and then I try to edit a cell, if I click on a second cell the table tries to goes back to the first page (I can see the first page for half a second before it comes back to the search). This bug is only happening when I use the global search then try to edit it.

I also created a codespace if you want to check the issue : https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/blazing-bird-c7cz3m

Here is my component:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useTable, usePagination, useGlobalFilter, Column } from 'react-table';
import {
  Box,
  Flex,
  Table,
  Tbody,
  Td,
  Th,
  Thead,
  Tr,
  Text,
  IconButton,
  Input,
} from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { ArrowBackIcon, ArrowForwardIcon } from '@chakra-ui/icons';

interface Row {
  [key: string]: any;
}

interface EditableCellProps {
  value: any;
  row: {
    index: number;
  };
  column: {
    id: string;
  };
  updateMyData: (index: number, id: string, value: any) => void;
}

const EditableCell: React.FC<EditableCellProps> = ({
  value: initialValue,
  row: { index },
  column: { id },
  updateMyData,
}) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);

  const onChange = (e: any) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };

  const onBlur = () => {
    updateMyData(index, id, value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(initialValue);
  }, [initialValue]);

  return <Input value={value} onChange={onChange} onBlur={onBlur} />;
};

const defaultColumn: Column<Row> = {
  Cell: EditableCell,
};

interface EditableTableProps {
  columns: Array<Column<Row>>;
  data: Array<Row>;
  updateMyData: (index: number, id: string, value: any) => void;
  skipPageReset: boolean;
}

const EditableTable: React.FC<EditableTableProps> = ({
  columns,
  data,
  updateMyData,
  skipPageReset,
}) => {
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState('');

  const handleSearchChange = (e: any) => {
    setSearchValue(e.target.value);
  };

  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    prepareRow,
    page,
    canPreviousPage,
    canNextPage,
    pageOptions,
    pageCount,
    gotoPage,
    nextPage,
    previousPage,
    setPageSize,
    state: { pageIndex, pageSize },
    setGlobalFilter,
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data,
      defaultColumn,
      autoResetPage: !skipPageReset,
      updateMyData,
    },
    useGlobalFilter,
    usePagination,
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    setGlobalFilter(searchValue || undefined);
  }, [searchValue, setGlobalFilter, skipPageReset]);

  return (
    <Box>
      <Flex alignItems="center" mb={4}>
        <Input
          placeholder="Search..."
          value={searchValue}
          onChange={handleSearchChange}
        />
      </Flex>
      <Table {...getTableProps()}>
        <Thead>
          {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
            <Tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                <Th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render('Header')}</Th>
              ))}
            </Tr>
          ))}
        </Thead>
        <Tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {page.map((row, i) => {
            prepareRow(row);
            return (
              <Tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                  return (
                    <Td
                      {...cell.getCellProps()}
                      borderBottomWidth="2px"
                      borderBottomColor="gray.200"
                    >
                      {cell.render('Cell')}
                    </Td>
                  );
                })}
              </Tr>
            );
          })}
        </Tbody>
      </Table>
      <Flex justifyContent="space-between" alignItems="center" px="25px">
        <Flex alignItems="center">
          <Text fontSize="sm" color="gray.500" fontWeight="normal" mr={2}>
            Page {pageIndex + 1} of {pageOptions.length}
          </Text>
        </Flex>
        <Flex alignItems="center">
          <Text fontSize="sm" color="gray.500" mr={2}>
            Total Records: {data.length}
          </Text>
        </Flex>
        <Flex>
          <IconButton
            icon={<ArrowBackIcon />}
            onClick={() => previousPage()}
            disabled={!canPreviousPage}
            variant="outline"
            mr="2"
            pointerEvents={canPreviousPage ? 'auto' : 'none'}
            aria-label={''}
          />
          <IconButton
            icon={<ArrowForwardIcon />}
            onClick={() => nextPage()}
            disabled={!canNextPage}
            variant="outline"
            pointerEvents={canNextPage ? 'auto' : 'none'}
            aria-label={''}
          />
        </Flex>
      </Flex>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default EditableTable;


and below is how I call this component :
import React from 'react';
import EditableTable from "components/editabletable/EditableTable"

const columns = [
    {
        Header: 'Name',
        accessor: 'name',
    },
    {
        Header: 'Age',
        accessor: 'age',
    },
    {
        Header: 'Email',
        accessor: 'email',
    },
];


const bdata = [
    {
        name: 'John Doe',
        age: 25,
        email: 'john@example.com',
        city: 'New York',
        country: 'USA'
    },
    {
        name: 'Jane Smith',
        age: 30,
        email: 'jane@example.com',
        city: 'London',
        country: 'UK'
    },
    {
        name: 'Bob Johnson',
        age: 35,
        email: 'bob@example.com',
        city: 'Paris',
        country: 'France'
    }
]
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(() => bdata);
  const [originalData] = React.useState(data);
  const [skipPageReset, setSkipPageReset] = React.useState(false);

  const updateMyData = (rowIndex: number, columnId: any, value: any) => {
    setSkipPageReset(true);
    setData((old) =>
      old.map((row, index) => {
        if (index === rowIndex) {
          return {
            ...old[rowIndex],
            [columnId]: value,
          };
        }
        return row;
      })
    );
  };
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setSkipPageReset(false);
    }, 100);

    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, [data, originalData]);
  return (
    <div>
      <EditableTable
        columns={columns}
        data={data}
        updateMyData={updateMyData}
        skipPageReset={skipPageReset}
      />
    </div>
  );

I tried adding a timeout / delay and tried callbacks to fix this issue but the best I could achieve is just returning to the current page search if the table tries to reset it to the first page.
